# Polymorphic Paths for Custom Routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= collection.each do |record| %>
    <%= link_to record.name, polymorphic_path([:admin, record]) %>
<% end %>
```

Breaks with this route:

```
resources :users, as: "authors", path: "authors", except: [:create, :destroy]
```

Error:

```
undefined method `admin_user_path'
```

Can anyone help?

I've got it as a Rails bug

Comment: The problem is it's taking the `model_name` as the path builder var, but I can't find any documentation on how to change it?

Answer (score 1):

You should also define users resource inside admin namespace

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I forgot to mention is *is* already in the admin namespace :) It's the `path:` and `as:` arguments which are causing the issue. The object is from the `User` model, and the polymorphic_path helper is using that